# Find string in file using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, search, find

sorry for my bad english, please help if you can.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 if (File.Exists(@"data.txt"))
                {
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"data.txt");

                     while (file.EndOfStream != true)
                      {
                        string s = file.ReadLine();
                        string s2 = file.ReadLine();
                        string s3 = file.ReadLine();
                        string s4 = file.ReadLine();

                        Match m = Regex.Match(s, "ID\\s");
                        Match m2 = Regex.Match(s2, "Spec\\s");
                        Match m3 = Regex.Match(s3, "Category\\s");
                        Match m4 = Regex.Match(s4, "Price\\s");

                        if (m.Success && m2.Success && m3.Success && m4.Success)
                        {

                             // some code 

                        }
                      }
                }
                if (!File.Exists(@"data.txt")) MessageBox.Show("The file is missing!");
            }
```

Text file content:

```
ID  560
Spec    This ... bla bla 

blah...
blah...
bla bla 
bla
Category    Other
Price   $259.95 


ID  561
Spec    more blah blah...

blah...
blah...
bla bla 
bla
Category    Other
Price   $229.95
```

I just want to get the text after `ID`, everything after `Spec` until `Category`. 
In this example (above) i need:

```
560
```

and

```
This ... bla bla 

    blah...
    blah...
    bla bla 
    bla


561
```

and

```
more blah blah...

    blah...
    blah...
    bla bla 
    bla
```

and so on, until end of the file is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I parsed a bunch of files much like this. Use a text reader to read in the data into an Ienumerable like below. This is not working code but to give you the concept. It should get you in the right direction.

```
 TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
 IEnumerable<string> data = this.ReadLines(reader);  

 foreach (var s in data){
     // make sure its not null doesn't start with an empty line or something.
     if (s != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && !s.StartsWith("  ") && s.Length > 0){
        s = s.ToLower().Trim();

        // use regex to find some key in your case the "ID".
        // look into regex and word boundry find only lines with ID
        // double check the below regex below going off memory. \B is for boundry
        var regex = new Regex("\BID\B");
        var isMatch = regex.Match(s.ToLower());
        if(isMatch.Success){ 
           // split the spaces out of the line.
           var arr = s.split(' ');
           var id = arr[1]; // should be second obj in array.

        }

     }
 }
```

Here is a parse file I use in an actual project that pareses this very type of text file. It uses an xml file for templating so that the file can be used for various files. However it will give you an idea of what's possible or maybe a few other ideas that could help. [parse.cs](http://www.origin1.com/downloads/parse.txt)

Comment: Thanks mate, but I'm new in C# and can't make it mayself.

Comment: the above should actually be pretty close for you. Just replace "path" with your path to the file in question. Stack is not really designed to provide complete solutions. If you need to hire someone you might check ODesk or something like that. Really you should try the above though again it should be rather close. Welcome to edit/post back and I'll help you through it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, maybe I should try there!

Comment: happy to assist if you want to battle through it.